# Why is object returned from getDefinitionByName()?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

In Actionscript 3, why does getDefinitionByName() return an Object when the docs say:

> Returns a reference to the class object of the class specified by the name  parameter.

Based on that, I would conclude that the returned object should be Class instead of Object. Can someone enlighten me why that is not the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

getDefinitionByName can also return a Function, such as getDefinitionByName('flash.utils.getDefinitionByName').
This only works on namespace-level functions, though, not static class methods.

Comment: This is the correct answer, someone should update this question.

Answer (score 6):

Despite the method signature, getDefinitionByName does return [Class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Class.html). I think the misleading signature is due to the method existing before the Class object (when it used to return an anonymous/extended object instance).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Adobe considered that this function might return different values in a future version of Flash Player. For instance, ECMAScript, the standard on which ActionScript is based, has historically used `Function` objects with prototypes as the basis for class-like objects. During discussions of the newest versions of the ECMAScript standard, there has been sugestions for "freezing" function-based classes at run-time to make them into something like compile-time `Class` objects. What if you could also specify a definition name for them? Are they actually of type `Class` at this point, or are they still or type `Function`? Probably the later, in my opinion. Both 'Class' and 'Function' references can be generalized as `Object`, so that return type makes sense in this context.

Note: This explanation is purely speculation based on what I've read in the [ECMAScript specification wiki](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php) and the blogs of various committee members.